# square Facebook pictures

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Graph API I can get small, large, medium pictures. Or I can get small square picture.

But how can I get large square picture? Is there any service I can use?

Answer (score 33):

Simple, I just found this out.

Example,

https://graph.facebook.com/friends_Id/picture?width=200&height=200

tada~

Comment: Nice, but the url actually gives unpredictable result size for different users.
When it set it 128&128 - it appears the same size for every profile user

Comment: The related [Facebook API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/) say this will return " a square image if width and height have the same value." However, in my own testing of a photo from an album, both the returned width and height were larger than 200, and the result was not square either. I tried [filing a bug on that doc page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create/doc?doc_path=%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fapi%2Fphoto%2F) but I got back an error: "We currently only accept bugs in English"... even though my report was in English.

Comment: You'll get a square picture for most users, but for some users you might get a non-square picture, of the width you requested but of a different height. And indeed if you look closely the documentation makes no guarantee that you'll get a square image.

Answer (score 6):

Oddly enough, Facebook itself doesn't use a bigger square image even though they show a bigger squared profile picture on the new timeline pictures. If you take a closer look they take a larger rectangular image and reposition it inside an HTML element as Michael proposed above.

I would expect that at some point the positioning data they use for this will be released via the API but I am not aware of that data being available yet. I've had times where this would have been helpful also and have thus far either just centered the image or used the top portion. Not ideal though since FB already allows for and tracks custom positioning of the most important "square" of the image via their "icon" creator.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this officially, here's a silly hack. The following code will make sure the image is no wider/taller than 120 pixels. If it is, then the image will overflow outside the  element:

```html
<div style="width: 120px; height: 120px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="{$image}" align="absmiddle" width=120 style="min-width: 120px; min-height: 120px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not maintain the original aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 3):

> You can specify the picture size you want with the type argument, which should be one of square (50x50), small (50 pixels wide, variable height), and large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height).

From the [Graph API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Those are the only three sizes available. You can use a bigger version of the 50x50 image but it'll obviously look dithered.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy. But what if I need for example 180px/180px profile picture?

Comment: Like I said, those are your options. The only way to make it 180x180 is either cropping the large image yourself, or enlarging the 50x50 image using a straight HTML attribute.

Comment: +1, @Sergey long story short...Facebook will not do your homework! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays Graph actually could return you square image of any size. They cache most common sizes (like 100x100, 128x128) and return the closest size by the following [request (hover to see)](https://graph.facebook.com/1377492801/picture?type=square&width=100&height=100&return_ssl_resources=1)

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers already stated, in facebook the square pictures are only in `50x50` resolution.

A simple CSS hack does the trick though:

Query the large image, wrap the `img`-tag with a `div` and apply this CSS to the div:

```css
img#facebook_img {
 width: YOUR_WIDTH;
}
div#wrapper {
 height: YOUR_HEIGHT;  
 overflow: hidden;  
}
```

If `YOUR_WIDTH` and `YOUR_HEIGHT` are the same you get your square image and the ratio is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked perfectly for me, having come across profile pictures of various dimensions (some with a greater height than expected, some with a smaller height) which ended up either stretched or non-centered.

In the end I used a `div` element instead of an `img` and set the image through a `background-image` `style` attribute rather than through its `src` attribute.

CSS file:

```
.profile-pic {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div style="background-image:url(https://graph.facebook.com/123/picture?width=120&height=120);" class="profile-pic"></div>
```

Replace 120px in the above (occurs twice in the CSS and twice in the HTML fragment) with your desired dimensions.

Comment: Note: At the moment, when requesting a 100x100px image, Facebook gives an always square image. Request the same image at a different size, however, such as 120x120px, and you may get a non-square image of 120px width but a different height.