# How to get facebook profile large square picture ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook profile picture is public available. 
For example https://graph.facebook.com/oleg.dats/picture It's square but to small 
 
To get larger picture https://graph.facebook.com/oleg.dats/picture?type=large But this one is not square. 
Is there way to get square profile picture (200px/200px) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [square Facebook pictures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796939/square-facebook-pictures)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You will need to post process it yourself. The sizes are

- square (50x50)
- small (50 pixels wide, variable height)
- normal (100 pixels wide, variable height), and
- large (about 200 pixels wide, variable height)

Announced as of Wednesday, August 22, 2012,

You can query for alternate sizes via Graph API using `width` and `height`, for example

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/1207059/picture?width=121&height=100
```

So in your case

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oleg.dats/picture?width=200&height=200
```

Or in FQL

`SELECT url, real_width, real_height FROM profile_pic WHERE id=100000896260238 AND width=200 AND height=200`

<sub>[Source - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/22/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/]</sub>

Comment: It's interesting how FB is doing this on https://www.facebook.com/oleg.dats?sk=friends page. The images look square

Comment: But how do you get the correctly square cropped in high resolution? When i use width height I get a square but vertically centerred image.. which often shows the chest..

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to get the profile picture of any size:

https://graph.facebook.com/digitizor/picture?width=700&height=200

This shows the profile picture of facebook.com/digitizor in 700px by 200px

Change dimensions and facebook profile name as per your requirements

http://digitizor.com/2012/09/15/graphi-api-profile-picture/