# get facebook profile picture using facebook username

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried https://graph.facebook.com/username/picture?type=square .but I got this error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (user.name)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Comment: `OAuthException` - looks like an authentication exception - have you authenticated the request?

Comment: Use userid instead of username

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get facebook profile large square picture ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743768/how-to-get-facebook-profile-large-square-picture)

Comment: definitely not a duplicate of that other thread, it´s about getting the picture by username, not about getting a specific version of the picture. see my answer, it´s a well known error message since v2.0 of the graph api.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message tells you, it´s not possible to use the username for that anymore. You can only get the profile picture of a user after [authorizing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) him with basic permissions and using his (App Scoped) ID:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[app-scoped-id]/picture?type=square
```

In general, it is not possible to get any user details (or his picture) without authorizing, for privacy reasons. Check out the changelog for more information about the privacy changes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Don´t use tools like "findmyfbid", because they are scraping the ID from the user profile, which is not allowed. Also, you will only get the "global" ID that way, and you are not supposed to use that one either.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to Put the User Id Instead of name

Like

https://graph.facebook.com/669515255/picture?type=square

Comment: You Will Get that From Facebook Api Call. Explain what is actual Need.

Answer (score -3):

You should grants all permission then fire URL again see what results comes.